# Odoo 12: Pass data to Qweb report template

Tags: odoo-12

I want to send dictionnary to my qweb report template but it gives me error like this:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
Error to render compiling AST
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
Template: 1364
Path: /templates/t/t/t/t/div/h1/t
Node:< t t-esc="data['this']"/>
Here is my .py code located iny models folder:

```
class ReportMenumenu(models.AbstractModel):
    _inherit = "my.model"

@api.model
def _get_report_values(self, docids, data=None):
    data = {'this': 'test'}
    return {
        'doc_ids': self.ids,
        'doc_model': self.model,
        'data': data,
    }
```

And here is the report template that take the data:

```
<odoo>
<template id="my_module.report_name">
    <t t-call="web.html_container">
        <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="o">
            <t t-call="web.external_layout">
                <div class="
                    <h1>
                        <t t-esc="data['this']"/>
                    </
                </div>
            </t>
        </t>
    </t>
</template></odoo>
```

Can you help me? Thank you.

Comment: I take example from sale/report/sale_report.py and now it works.

Comment: maybe data=None gives you problems